# How to return historical data from Dark Sky API Time Machine

Tags: javascript, json, darksky

I'm trying to build a web application that can compare current weather conditions with those of a previous date using the Dark Sky API. My end goal would be to be able to select a date, click the "Get Data" button, and view the following results:

```
Current Weather           Weather on Chosen Date     Difference 
- today's temperature     - previous temp            - x degrees warmer/cooler
- today's humidity        - previous humidity        - x percent more/less humid
- etc                     - etc                      - etc
```

I have an example work in progress on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/mikejandreau/pen/ExjxQGE

The `apiKey` is currently exposed - it will be changed and obscured in production.

In the example, the top section has the user location using geolocation data and the current date/time. The "Current" panel successfully shows current weather conditions, and the Fahrenheit/Celsius toggle works.

This is a truncated version of the call to Dark Sky, with just the Time Machine line (full version on CodePen example):

```js
// Retrieve location and data from JSON on load.
$(window).on("load", function () {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

            // geologation for weather data
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;

            $.getJSON("https://api.darksky.net/forecast/"+apiKey+"/"+lat+","+lon+","+previousDate+"?exclude=currently,flags", getHistoricalData);

        });
    } else {
        alert("Browser doesn't support geolocation!");
    }
});
```

The `previousDate` variable is using a UNIX time stamp that is currently declared above `(window).on("load", function()`. Conceptually, I think the process that needs to happen is the date gets selected and the button is clicked, the date is converted to a UNIX time stamp, said time stamp is appended to the `getJSON` call. This is where I'm stuck, since the historical data doesn't seem to be working.

This should update the text based on the JSON data (line 180 on CodePen example):

```js
// HTML data display from JSON.
var getHistoricalData = function(dataHist) {
    console.log(dataHist);
    $("#past_date").text(formattedTime);
    $("#past_summary").text(dataHist.hourly.data.summary);
    $("#past_degree").html(tempConvert(dataHist.hourly.data.temperature));
    $("#past_humidity").html(Math.round(dataHist.hourly.data.humidity * 100));
    $("#past_precip").html(Math.round(dataHist.daily.data[0].precipProbability * 100));
    $("#past_wind-speed").html(Math.round(dataHist.hourly.data.windSpeed * 1.6));
};
```

The Dark Sky documentation has zero working examples that I can reverse engineer, and while there are functioning demos of the API, I have not yet found a functioning example of the Time Machine functionality.

Not sure what I'm missing, but any pointers would be appreciated.